# How do i see where the extensions are for a git project?

Tags: git, autorest

The [Autorest project](https://github.com/Azure/autorest) is referenced by other projects like [the autorest csharp projecct](https://github.com/Azure/autorest.csharp)  which does mention that it is a "Extension for AutoRest (https://github.com/Azure/autorest) that generates C# code"

It took me some time to figure this out
How do I find out what the other extensions are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [autorest](https://github.com/Azure/autorest) and [autorest.csharp](https://github.com/Azure/autorest.csharp) are repositories in the [Azure organization](https://github.com/Azure).

If you're just looking for the other repositories within that organization that are also autorest extensions, you can perform [a simple GitHub query for repositories that follow the same naming convention](https://github.com/search?p=1&q=org%3AAzure%20%22azure.autorest%22&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

EDIT: For this particular project, [this document listing the code generation extensions is maintained](https://github.com/Azure/autorest/blob/master/docs/trampoline.md).

Comment: The specific query I used is `org:Azure "azure.autorest"`. And yeah, typing in a query from the Azure organization page defaults to searching within the org (i.e `org:Azure`). The quotes around `azure.autorest` also filter out a false positive.

Here's the [documentation on querying for repositories](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-repositories/).